# How to concat two row data in mysql if they are the same

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table where I some data are repeated in one column but have different value in another. I want to concat them an them and create new string.

I am getting data in following format:
[image]

See rows with *checkbox option*  and  *vodaphoneissues and comments* are repeated twice, yet have different values in another column.

I want to concatenate that value with comma separated format.

Comment: You need to include column headings with the data; we shouldn't have to guess which columns you are referring to.  On the whole, it would be better not to show the image; enter the data in a table in the SO question.  An outline schema of the table would help, and should include the primary key specification.  It looks as if the first column got clipped; some of the numbers appear to have part of another digit beforehand.  With your sample input data, you should show also your desired output.  Often, 5 rows of input data is sufficient (keep it small).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function called GROUP_CONCAT.

I do not know names of your columns, let's say they are COLUMN1, COLUMN2, etc. The code will be:

```
SELECT COLUMN3, GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN4) FROM your_table GROUP BY COLUMN3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for that purposes

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT column_name ORDER BY column_name SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM table 
GROUP BY comments, versions;
```

Also pay attention to `GROUP BY` clouse as it groups by few columns:

```
GROUP BY comments, versions;
```